# Can I get a temporary US driver's license from within Japan?

Tags: driving-license

I'm trying to go to the US, and I will only be there for 6 days.  I want to be able to drive while I'm there.  Can I get a temporary license?

Comment: Welcome to expatriates.SE.  This question is probably more appropriate for travel.SE.  And if you have a driver's license in Japan you can drive with it as long as you have IDP.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about travel.

Comment: @Karlson Thanks.  When I searched about licenses, I got a lot of results on here.  Sorry.  Feel free to migrate.  Meanwhile: What's an IDP?

Comment: http://www.dmv.org/international-driver-permits.php ?

Comment: http://www.aaa.com/vacation/idpf.html This is in the US.  You will need to find the same for Japan

Comment: The rules are different for every state. For many states, visitors can just use a foreign driver's license without anything else. For those states, an IDP is irrelevant and they "don't recognize" it. There is no general answer for all of the U.S.

Comment: @user102008 Thanks, big guy.  How about Cali?

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: In California an adult visitor can just use any valid foreign or out of state license.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you want is an International Driving Permit (IDP).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Driving_Permit

Do **not** fall for the "international driving licence" scams, you just need the IDP. They are usually easy to get from the same place where you would apply for a driving licence. Here in Thailand, you can get one from the Department of Land Transport, and in the UK I have got one from the Post Office before.

The permit is valid in every country except for the country it is issued in (because you should already have a driving licence in that country in order to qualify for the permit, I guess).

The cost is nominal (not a lot), and validity is one year from the date of issue.